# get_post_meta() not display field value for first item in wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress custom field that I use to assign a custom class to some scrollable elements to obtain a landor style effect. I have a problem with the `get_post_meta()` function, It will display only the field value for the second post of the loop, but not the first one. I'm using a custom post type, but I don't think that this is the problem. Is there any solution?
Here is the code:

```
<?php $item = new WP_Query( ['post_type' => 'home-slider', 'posts_per_page' => 3] ); ?>
<?php if( $item->have_posts() ): while( $item->have_posts() ): $item->the_post(); ?>
<?php $class = get_post_meta($post->ID,'class',true); ?>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 img-<?php echo $class; ?>"> <!-- custom class -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 img-text">
            <h1 class="">Hello</h1>
            <p class="lead">Nice to meet you.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="img-fluid bg-img" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
      </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked there is meta for both post items?

Comment: Yes, the key and the values are saved inside the db, but only the first isn't displayed! can be the `top` word the problem?I've named the class field value top.

Comment: get_post_meta with the third argument as true, will only get you the first item in the array. is that what you are hoping for?

Comment: if I `var_dump()` the classvalue with the third param set to false it will return an empty array, but with true it will only load the class for the second post.

Answer (score 0):

You need change the $post->ID to get_the_ID().
Hope help.

Comment: already tried and I get the same result!The function is inside the loop so the `$post` variable is available.

Comment: Are you check count items?

Comment: what you mean for count item?

Comment: For example count(item->get_posts()).

Comment: May be in items Just second post.

Comment: Nope, I've checked and inside the db the value are saved and the returned posts by the loop are two, this is what I expect, the value still remain empty for the first post.

Comment: It's very strange

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a solution to the problem. To test if this was an issue related to the post type I've registered a new one and I've added the same field to manage the custom classes needed. The result is that all works fine, I think that there is a problem with the post type where I was trying to add the custom field, because I've added the custom field support later than the post type was created and inserted inside the wordpress database. 
Thanks for the help!